# Дублируются элементы при повторном открытии окна

Tags: java

При повторном нажатии кнопки Register дублируются элементы.
Пробывал через dispose,но все так же.
Как исправить эту ошибку?

```js
package Client;


import Client.packet.PackerAuthorize;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Authorization extends JFrame {

  static JTextField smallField;
  JTextField bigField;

  public Authorization() {
    smallField = new JTextField(12);
    smallField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Authorization.this,
          "Ваше слово: " + smallField.getText());
      }
    });
    final JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField(12);
    password.setEchoChar('*');
    JPanel contents = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    contents.add(smallField);
    contents.add(password);
    setContentPane(contents);
    setSize(400, 100);
    setLocation(800, 200);
    setTitle("authorization");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JPanel jpBotton = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
    add(jpBotton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    JButton jbStart = new JButton("Login");
    JButton jbExite = new JButton("Register");
    jpBotton.add(jbStart);
    jpBotton.add(jbExite);
    jbStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        ClientLoader.sendPacket(new PackerAuthorize(smallField.getText(), password.getText()));
        try {
          DataInputStream dis = null;
          try {
            dis = new DataInputStream(ClientLoader.getSocket().getInputStream());
          } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
          }
          if (dis.available() <= 0) {
            if (dis.readUTF().equals("error")) {
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error!");
              System.out.println("error");
            } else {
              new Chat();
              setVisible(false);
              System.out.println("successful");
            }
            try {
              Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
          }
        } catch (IOException ex) {}
      }
    });
    jbExite.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Register log = new Register();
        setVisible(false);
      }
    });
    setVisible(true);
  }
  public static String getNickname() {
    return smallField.getText();
  }
}
```

```js
package Client;

import Client.packet.PackerRegistration;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Register {
  public static JFrame frame = new JFrame("BoxLayoutTest");
  public static void createUI(Container container) {

    final JButton button = new JButton("Registration"); //static что бы закрыть
    JButton calc = new JButton("Calc_test"); //static что бы закрыть
    button.setAlignmentY(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    calc.setAlignmentY(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    final JTextField smallField, password, repitPassword;
    smallField = new JTextField(12);
    password = new JTextField(12);
    repitPassword = new JTextField(12);
    container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    container.add(new JLabel("Logim:"));
    container.add(smallField);
    container.add(new JLabel("Password :"));
    container.add(password);
    container.add(new JLabel("Repit password :"));
    container.add(repitPassword);
    container.add(button);
    container.add(calc);

    calc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        new Chat();
      }
    });
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public int hashCode() {
        return super.hashCode();
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == button) {
          Map < Integer, String > states = new HashMap < Integer, String > ();
          states.put(1, smallField.getText());
          states.put(2, password.getText());
          states.put(3, repitPassword.getText());

          System.out.println(ClientLoader.getSocket());
          ClientLoader.sendPacket(new PackerRegistration(states.get(1), states.get(2), states.get(3)));
          try {
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(ClientLoader.getSocket().getInputStream());
            if (dis.available() <= 0) {
              if (dis.readUTF().equals("error")) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error!");

                System.out.println("error");
              } else {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                Authorization p = new Authorization();
              }
              try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
              } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
            }
          } catch (IOException ex) {}
        }
      }
    });
  }
  public Register() {
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    createUI(frame.getContentPane());
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        // Открытие окна
        frame.setLocation(800, 200);
        frame.setTitle("authorization");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нажал на кнопку регистрации,зарегестрировался.Захотел зарегестрировать еще одну запись,и окно дублируется

Comment: вы зря зацепились за метод createui, он не для этого. поставьте там бряку, он много раз вызывается у Вас

Comment: А что будет если нажать на кнопку с крестиком?